# Error during product-collection because of already existing ID

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

The following code should retrieves all products in categeroy 3,11,31 and 8.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'category_id',array('in' => array("3","11","31","8")))));
```

but it generates the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "350" already exist' in /home/huisent/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373 Stack trace: #0 /home/huisent/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(265): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) #1 /home/huisent/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1055): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) #2 /home/huisent/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false) #3 /home/huisent/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load() #4 [internal function]: Varien_Data_Collection->count() #5 /home/huisent/public_html/staging/advertentieFeed/test3.php(61): count(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resour in /home/huisent/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 373
```

It turns out that product with id=350 occurs in 2 of those categeries and that's not allowed/working in Magento. Is there a way to retrieve all the products anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue with your collection, is that if your join limits the result set, you can use `INNER JOIN`, instead of `JEFT JOIN`. It works better for performance.

The second issue, that in joined table, there are multiple combinations of products that are assigned into both categories at the same time, so MySQL queries returns two records of the same product, that is why collection is throwing an error. You can use group by statement by product identifier, in order to solve this issue, but it may result in performance bottleneck when your unfiltered data set is huge. In that case you might need to create custom Magento index for those categories.

The third issue, that you are not using resource model or customized collection to change collection select, that will be a problem for you in the feature to maintain your application.

Comment: Okay but can you show me the correct code for issue 1 and 2?

Comment: For first one just change one of the arguments. For second one add `group()` statement for collection select, here is a sample: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/how-to-use-group-by-option-for-mage-core-model-resource-db-collection-abstract

Comment: I'm a bit of a NOOB but I tried this $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'inner')->getSelect()->group('product_id') but did doesn't work. Can you help direct me how to use it in a proper way